# Weight = 8.4, which is > 6 but < 10. So code should take weight * 4.0 + 20, but it does weight * 3.0 +20

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently working on my python course and I have some code here:

```
weight = 8.4

#Ground Shipping

if weight <= 2:
  cost_ground = weight * 1.5 + 20
elif weight > 2 <= 6:
  cost_ground = weight * 3.0 + 20
elif weight > 6 <= 10:
  cost_ground = weight * 4.0 + 20
else:
  cost_ground = weight * 4.75 + 20

print('Ground Shipping $',cost_ground)
```

However, when I print the result I am getting

Ground Shipping $ 45.2

Why is this? 8.4 is greater than 6 and less than 10, so it should be multiplying by 4.0 not 3.0

Comment: You should use `2 < weight <= 6` for these comparisons. As it is now, the code is checking whether both `weight > 2` and `2 <= 6`, which is why it's multiplying by 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
weight = 8.4

#Ground Shipping

if weight <= 2:
  cost_ground = weight * 1.5 + 20
elif 2 < weight <= 6:
  cost_ground = weight * 3.0 + 20
elif 6 < weight <= 10:
  cost_ground = weight * 4.0 + 20
else:
  cost_ground = weight * 4.75 + 20

print('Ground Shipping $',cost_ground)
```

Your elif condition is set wrong. For elif weight > 2 <= 6 , weight = 8.4 the first weight>2 is true and then 2<=6 is also true and the entire expressions evaluates to true and the elif block is run.